# PHP mysql_num_rows "no results" message?

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine, mysql-num-rows

I have a MySQL keyword search on my website and it works fine. The problem is when someone searches a keyword I haven't added, nothing shows up on the results page.

Instead of nothing showing up I would like to have a `no results found` message.

So I used the code below:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($Recordset1) > 0) {
    // no results
    echo 'No results found.';
} else {
    do {
    // output
    } while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1));
}
```

The problem is whenever I search a keyword knowing it is in my db, I get my results along with a `no results found` message. (The `no results found` message also appears on the top left of my webpage pushing my entire website down.)

And when I searched a keyword I knew was not in my db, I didn't get a message at all, it showed nothing like before.

I played around with the greater, less than, and equal signs and got similar problems. I was told my logic was backwards, but I'm not sure how it should look.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

do {} while loops aren't suitable for database fetching, unless you do a row fetch BEFORE entering the loop. For the first iteration of your output section, there won't be any results fetched from the database, so you'd be outputting essentially nothing.

mysql_num_rows() would return a 0 if there are no results, so you're actually inverting th elogic, saying there are no rows when there really are. Even a single row of results would make `> 0` return a true and output "no results".

Answer (score 1):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($Recordset1) == 0) {
// no results
echo 'No results found.';
} else {
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)) {
// output
}
}
```

try it...

1.) if no result then mysql_num_rows would be 0
2.) before getting output you should fetch it to a variable not after using it

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($Recordset1) == 0) {
 . . .
```

Comment: for some reason that's making my search stop working all together.

Answer (score 0):

Change your if condition to

```
if (mysql_num_rows($Recordset1) == 0) {
```

When you use `> 0` it means that "there are results" and **not** "no results found".

Comment: for some reason that's making my search stop working all together